# EF Core searching for non-existent table when accessing linking-table entries

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, db-first

I use EF Core (nuget package versions: 8.0.2) and the DB-first aproach.

I have created the DB models from my DB (using the automatic scaffolding), with attributes included, but when I try to fetch a document from the DB, I get this error:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid object name 'Document.CitizenRequestKindDocument'.'

This table does not exist and I am not sure why it doesn't use the names from the attributes to fetch data.

This happens when trying to access the property `IdCitizenRequestKinds` from below:

```
[Table("Document", Schema = "Document")]
public partial class Document
{
    [Key]
    public int IdDocument { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    [ForeignKey("IdDocument")]
    [InverseProperty("IdDocuments")]
    public virtual ICollection<CitizenRequestKind> IdCitizenRequestKinds { get; set; } = new List<CitizenRequestKind>();
    ...
    ...
}



[Table("CitizenRequestKind", Schema = "Document")]
public partial class CitizenRequestKind
{
    [Key]
    public int IdCitizenRequestKind { get; set; }
    ...
    ...
    [ForeignKey("IdCitizenRequestKind")]
    [InverseProperty("IdCitizenRequestKinds")]
    public virtual ICollection<Document> IdDocuments { get; set; } = new List<Document>();
}
```

The special thing about this DB-model is that it uses a linking table in the DB:

[image: DB schema]

Note that the linking table is not even present on the auto-generated DB-models.

I have tried defining a relationship like that, but it didn't seem to change anything:

```
        var docBuilder = modelBuilder.Entity<Document>();
        docBuilder.HasMany(e => e.IdCitizenRequestKinds).WithMany(e => e.IdDocuments);
```

How can this work, preferably without introducing the linking table into the DB models?

Comment: There are no DB models in EF Core. The model describes entities and their mapping to tables. If you don't specify a table name for a table or a many-to-many relation it will infer it based on naming conventions. In the question, there's a many-to-many relation between `Document` and `CitizenRequestKind` so a bridge table *must* exists in the database. BTW violating the naming conventions (eg `IdCitizenRequestKinds` instead of Id or EnttityNameId) is never a good idea.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos This is an old DB I am accessing. I cannot change things easily. The `CitizenRequest` table is my link-table in my case. Is there a way to specify its name somehow while configuring an entity? In the last code-snippet, that does the configuration, I didn't notice an way to provide table names.

Comment: What are the actual classes and tables? The question shows `Document` but the image shows `CitizenRequest` in the `Document` schema with a highly unusual composite key. No `Document` or `Documents` table is visible. If you bypass all naming conventions you'll have to specify all names explicitly. Or create your own convention class that somehow generates the name `CitizenRequest` when it sees `Document` and `CitizenRequestKind`

Comment: The classes are `Document` and `CitizenRequestKind`. In the DB, there are the tables `Document`, `CitizenRequest`, and `CitizenRequestKind`. The one called `CitizenRequest` is a link-table, linking  `CitizenRequestKind` and `Document`.

Comment: `an way to provide table names.` you already do so using attributes. You can do the same in the model builder, using the Fluent API. That's well documented already, eg in the [Many-to-many with named join table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#many-to-many-with-named-join-table) of the Many-to-Many doc page. The [EF scaffolding tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/scaffolding/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) can generate the classes, using either attributes or the fluent API to specify the table names

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos My problem is that EF searches a table that does not exist, and probably is the linking-table which is missing from the classes. So, without a class, I cannot configure anything for that table, from what I can see. Is there a way to do this with the link-table class missing?

Comment: Ah! That `.UsingEntity("CitizenRequest")` is probably what I want... Yep. It has worked.